# Is there a way to go two directories back in cygwin (linux)?

Tags: terminal, cygwin, cd

I know that you can go back one directory in cygwin by using the dash (-).  But, how do you go back more than one directory in your history?

I've tried `cd --` it doesn't seem to work.  Thanks!  This would be very very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pushd` and `popd`. `pushd` adds a directory to stack, `popd` removes it. See `man bash` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Only previous dir is remembered, so Hunle's answer or some other way of remembering dirs is needed.